# Changing - css - backgroundColor function (pure javascript) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

Could anyone tell me why changing colour after performing onclick doesn't work here ?

```js
function butt(color) {
    if(document.getElementById("bt").style.backgroundColor=="green"){
            document.getElementById("bt").style.backgroundColor="purple";
    }
};
document.getElementById("bt").addEventListener("click", function() {
    butt("green")
});
```

```css
#bt {
    background-color:yellow;
    border-radius:10%;
    padding:10px;
    margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div id="forbutton">
        <button type="button" id="bt">It's me MrButton !</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is the button in a form? if so, your page will be posting back and so any js changes will be lost.  You need to prevent the default action in that case

Comment: A working Stack Snippet would be useful.

Comment: how `yellow == green` ? make any sense?

Comment: Also, your click won't do anything as it takes `style.backgroundColor`  from the inline style so it would ignore anything you add to your css file as it is not inline (you need to use something like `element.getComputedStyle`) - and as Sagar says you have used yellow but compared against green.  One final thing would be why are you passing a variable into the function but not using it?

Comment: @Pete is dead on. Your JavaScript can't grab the CSS style when it's set like that, so you would either need to use `.getComputedStyle` or set the background color with JavaScript (not preferred).

Comment: @Pete no, the button isn't in a form. I placed it in separate <row> including <div> as in the code snippet above.

Comment: sorry that should be `window.getComputedStyle(element).backgroundColour` - but it will return an rgb colour rather than `red` or `blue`

Comment: @Pete @ freginold Thanks guys I'm Newbie to programming. I didn't know it treats css including in separate file as inline-style and thanks for .getComputedStyle trick.

Comment: @hungerstar The idea was: first - yellow (I set it in separate css file), then after onclick changes for purple ... if the parameter in function was "green". I'm learning, wanted to know what it would happen :) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just passing the string "green" through the function. Details commented in Snippet.

**SNIPPET**

```js
// pass the string through function
function butt(color) {

  // If string is "green"...
  if (color === "green") {

    // Reference #bt and change it's backgroundColor to purple
    document.getElementById("bt").style.backgroundColor = "purple";
  }

};

// Register #bt to click event, when clicked...
document.getElementById("bt").addEventListener("click", function() {

  // Call butt() function passing the string "green"
  butt("green")
});
```

```css
#bt {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 10%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="forbutton">
    <button id="bt">It's me MrButton !</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Secondary point, it's possible the DOM isn't loading as well, so a readyState check wouldn't hurt. Otherwise, it will fail at trying to get the document element (null value otherwise)